# remove li containing string

Tags: jquery, string, html-lists

I want to trigger a delete of all LI within this UL if any of the LI contain stockTo.

This below, is not working.

```
var stockTo = 'abc';

$('ul#thelst li:contains(stock)').remove();
```

Comment: Where is stockTo defined ? Is it a string like `<li>stockTo</li>`, or a class? an id? Please past an html example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var stockTo = 'abc';
$('ul#thelst li:contains(' + stockTo + ')').parent().children().remove();
```

Comment: what is `parent().children()` about?

Comment: He wants to remove all the `li` elements within the `ul` where an `li` containing `stockTo` is found. His original code will just remove the `li` with `stockTo` in it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul#thelst li).contains('+ stockTo +').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

hey the way you have written your jQuery is not proper..

check the live demo here. [How to remove list](http://jsfiddle.net/kFkU6/1/)

BELOW IS THE HTML

```
<div>
    <ul id="thelst">
        <li>test test test test 111 </li>
        <li>test test test test 112 </li>
        <li>test test test test 113 </li>
        <li>test test test test 114 </li>
        <li>test test test test 115 </li>
        <li>test test test test 116 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

THIS IS THE JQUERY CODE INSIDE DOCUMENT READY FUNCTION

```
var stockTo = '114';

$('#thelst').find("li:contains(" + stockTo  + ")").remove();
```

**EDIT**
[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/kFkU6/3/) removing the list on click of anchor

Answer (score 1):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/m7zUh/

It will be good to see how your HTML look like but see the code below.

In the sample example: Click on trigger button and you will see `foo` will get removed as `li`

Hope this helps, :) have a good one, cheers

**HTML**

```
<div> sample</div>
<ul id="thelst"> 
    <li>Hulk</li>
        <li>Hawk</li>
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>Bar</li>
        <li>Rambo</li>
    </ul>

<input type="button" id="trigger" value="trigger" />
​
```

**Jquery code**

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {

    var stockTo = 'Foo';
    $('ul#thelst li:contains(' + stockTo + ')').remove();

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#thelst li:contains(' + stockTo + ')').remove();​
```